# AWK is not able to split a line when seperator is |||

Tags: awk, text-processing

Let's assume I have a file as follows (`file.txt`):

```
My name is John ||| Second part of example.
```

To get the first part (till `|||`)

I did the following:

```
awk -F '|||' '{print $1}' file.txt
```

However, this command gives me the whole line.

How can I get the portion of each line until `|||`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
awk -F"[|][|][|]" '{print $1}' file
My name is John
```

Second part

```
awk -F"[|][|][|]" '{print $2}' file
 Second part of example.
```

And as @glenn shows:

```
awk -F"[|]{3}" '{print $1}' file
My name is John
```

Comment: thanks, it works. But why normal escaping doesn't work here ?

Comment: @zwlayer No it does not.

Comment: @zwlayer normal escaping does work here but normal is not `-F"\|\|\|"` which I assume is what you thought would work.

Comment: Also, `-F '[|]{3}'`